# Check if a windows 8 tablet is connected to a power supply from windows 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a windows store application which will be used on tablet devices.

The application communicates with a service every 15 minutes but when the devices is connected to a power source I'd like to it to communication with the service every minute.

So is there any way in a windows 8 store application to check if a power supply is connected?

I'm using XAML/C# for the store application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's no access to the Power API in WinRT. If there was, you could use the SystemInformation.PowerStatus. If you're going to need 1 min polling to a server I'd strongly recommend using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) and it's [.NET client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client).

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Shame it's not possible yet.