# Device Status in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Are there any classes in Windows RunTime APIs to find the current device information(OS info, RAM size, power source) ?

The equivalent class in Windows Phone 8 is Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus (http://bit.ly/deviceStatus)

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge and what I've searched currently there is no method that will tell you that. Similar problem according to WinRT was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924303/2681948).

As I've also searched looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx), there is also no alternative to System.Power.

You can check [the battery status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.devices.power(v=vs.105).aspx) thought, but that won't help you to check if it is powered or not.

I'm also curious how this will be solved, hence IMO there should be such an ability when developing for phone to check if it's powered. Under WP8.0 for example BackgroundTransfers for large files required external power supply, and no I'm not able to check it - maybe it will be solved in final release.

Comment: @MohanRajNK Currently deviceinfo is limited on WP8.1 RT. [Here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) you have a API reference. If you find something usefull, please give a sign.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, there is currently no straightforward way to get the device info on a windows phone 8.1 runtime app although its possible to get some infor using the:

Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.aspx

Hope this helps